# Which performes better for a function based index: NVL2 or DECODE?

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing, oracle11g

I'd like to create a function based index in order to index NULL values in a column on an oracle 11g table.

Which performs better: NVL2 or DECODE?

`NVL2(nr.processed_datetime,'Y','N')`
or
`DECODE(nr.processed_datetime,NULL,'N','Y')`

Comment: kordirko, you need to revers one of your results: `NVL2(null,2,1)`

Comment: Have you tested in your environment with your data?  It seems exceptionally unlikely to me that there would be a measurable difference in performance (assuming your queries all use whatever construct you index).

Comment: Index construction is much heavier than these two functions so unlikely you can see some significant difference. As for me nvl2 is more natural here.

Answer (score -1):

To find a column value is null or not null you *NO need to use any function*. 
in your SQL where condition use  IS NULL or IS NOT NULL

Where nr.processed_datetime IS NULL ; 
or 
Where nr.processed_datetime IS NOT NULL;

for better performance, you can just crate normal index on that column that should be fine

Comment: Oracle does NOT index NULL.